# Focal loss for regression problems?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a regression problem with a training set which can be considered unbalanced. I therefore want to create a weighted loss function which values the loss contributions of hard and easy examples differently, with hard examples having a larger contribution.

I know this is possible type of weighted loss is possible as its implemented when using Focal loss.

My question is if its possible to convert focal loss for regression based problems using L1 loss and a linear output layer?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.cuda.amp as amp


##

class FocalLoss(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,
                 alpha=0.25,
                 gamma=2,
                 reduction='mean',):
        super(FocalLoss, self).__init__()
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.reduction = reduction
        self.crit = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss(reduction='none')

    def forward(self, logits, label):
        '''
        Usage is same as nn.BCEWithLogits:
            >>> criteria = FocalLoss()
            >>> logits = torch.randn(8, 19, 384, 384)
            >>> lbs = torch.randint(0, 2, (8, 19, 384, 384)).float()
            >>> loss = criteria(logits, lbs)
        '''
        probs = torch.sigmoid(logits)
        coeff = torch.abs(label - probs).pow(self.gamma).neg()
        log_probs = torch.where(logits >= 0,
                F.softplus(logits, -1, 50),
                logits - F.softplus(logits, 1, 50))
        log_1_probs = torch.where(logits >= 0,
                -logits + F.softplus(logits, -1, 50),
                -F.softplus(logits, 1, 50))
        loss = label * self.alpha * log_probs + (1. - label) * (1. - self.alpha) * log_1_probs
        loss = loss * coeff

        if self.reduction == 'mean':
            loss = loss.mean()
        if self.reduction == 'sum':
            loss = loss.sum()
        return loss
```